# What is the error here?? MySQL create table

Tags: mysql, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE `search` (    
 `title` text NOT NULL,    
 `description` text NOT NULL,    
 `link` text NOT NULL,    
 FULLTEXT KEY ('title','description')    
 )ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''title','description') )ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT
>   CHARSET=latin1' at line 5

Comment: Use backticks instead of single qoutes

Answer (score 0):

Your error message reveals that you use quotes instead of backticks.

Replace

```
FULLTEXT KEY ('title','description')
```

with

```
FULLTEXT KEY (`title`, `description`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you're missing the index name (key).

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE search (
title text NOT NULL,
description text NOT NULL,
link text NOT NULL,
FULLTEXT KEY mykey1 ('title','description')
)ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 0):

USE This

```
CREATE TABLE `search` (    
 `title` TEXT NOT NULL,    
 `description` TEXT NOT NULL,    
 `link` TEXT NOT NULL,    
 FULLTEXT KEY (`title`,`description`)   
 )ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE search (    
 title varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
 description varchar(100) NOT NULL,    
 link varchar(100) NOT NULL,    
 FULLTEXT KEY ('title', 'description')    
 )ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Try if this works.